# Desabilitar botão após o clique

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um form que envia curtidas para o meu banco de dados ao clicar no botão.

```
<form action="envia_curtir.php" method="post">
   <button class="icones icone-polegares-para-cima" id="botao"></button>
   <?=$curtida['curtidas'];?>
</form>
```

O que posso fazer para desabilitar o botão após o clique? Pois não quero que o botão seja acionado mais de uma vez.

Answer (score 5):

Utilizando JavaScript puro, você pode fazer utilizando:

```
<button onclick="this.disabled = true;">Curtir</button>
```

Comment: Estou utilizando javascript puro, porém da forma que você colocou o botão fica desabilitado sempre e não só depois de ter sido clicado.

Comment: @FrancisVagnerdaLuz o botão só será desabilitado após ter sido clicado. Por isso o evento `onclick`. Você quer que o botão seja habilitado novamente após o formulário ter sido enviado?

Comment: Então Daniel, mas eu coloquei código aqui e o botão ficou desabilitado mesmo antes de clicar

Answer (score 3):

Existem diversas formas de fazer isso, mas você basicamente precisará capturar o evento click e utilizar a propriedade disabled.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

```js
function desabilitaBotao(){
     document.getElementById("BtnCurtir").disabled = true;
}

$("#BtnCurtir2").on("click", function(){
  $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Existem diversas formas de você fazer isso -->
<button onclick="this.disabled = true;">Curtir</button>
<button onclick="desabilitaBotao()" id="BtnCurtir">Curtir</button>
<button id="BtnCurtir2">Curtir</button>
```

Comment: Sim Caique, é isso mesmo que estou precisando, mas sabe fazer isso sem utilizar o jquery?

Comment: Demonstrei 3 exemplos onde somente o ultimo é com Jquery.

Comment: A sim, desculpa...rs

Comment: Então @CaiqueRomero não sei o que está havendo aqui, mas não está funcionando, não sei porque.... esse é meu botão: <button class="icones icone-polegares-para-cima" id="botao" onclick="desabilitaBotao();"></button> e essa é a função que você me enviou e que coloquei aqui:   <script>
    function desabilitaBotao(){
     document.getElementById("botao").disabled = true;
}
  </script> Porém não dá certo... consegue identificar algum erro?

Comment: Existe uma forma mais fácil de você identifciar o erro, aperte F12 no navegar ele abrir a tela "ferramentas do desenvolvedor" nela existe uma aba escrito console. Se seu código possuir algum erro no Javascript essa aba exibirá para você.

Comment: então... eu chequei no console... não mostra erro algum.....Também já abri e fechei o browser, troquei de browser e não deu certo. O que acontece é que o botão já aparece desabilitado. Tentei também usando o Jquery mas também não deu... arg!!

Comment: cara tenta atualizar sua pergunta incluindo mais do seu código para podermos te auxiliar

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você usa Jquery:

```
<button onclick="dasabilitaBotao(this)">Curtir</button>
<script> 
    function desabilitaBotao(element){
    $(element).prop('disabled', true)
    }
</script>
```